# "It", "that", "this", and "what" as direct objects of "insist" and "care"

Tags: grammar

Can "it", "that", "this", and "what" be the direct object of these verbs "insist", and "care" when they're implying a sentence?

For example,

> 1. You insist what? You insist it? You insist that? You insist this?
> 2. You care what? You care it? You care that? You care this?

Here, if "what", "it", "that" and "this" all imply a sentence, I think there is no need to add prepositions as in

> You insist on what? You insist on it? You insist on that? You insist on this?
>
> You care about what? You care about it? You care about that? You care about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both, it depends on the context.  In general, "insist" takes a direct object that can be almost any noun, but you'd only use a pronoun when responding or referring to a prior comment:

> A: I insist you stop seeing my sister!  I insist **it**!
>   B: You insist **that/this**, do you?

To me, "insist *that*" sounds more natural, but I can't explain exactly why you'd choose to say "this" instead of "that" when referring to a prior comment.  In any case, you'd only say "insist what" if you didn't understand or were questioning a prior comment:

> A: I insist you stop seeing my sister!
>   B: You insist **what**?  Don't be absurd.

or

> B: You insist **what**?  I didn't hear you.

"Care" is similar, but (for whatever reason) I don't think either "care *it*" or "care *this*" is idiomatic.  "Care *that*" can be used when referring to a prior comment:

> A: I care that people aren't taking care of their gardens properly.
>   B: Why should you care **that**?  It's nice they grow gardens at all.

"Care *what*" can be used if you are responding to, or don't understand, a prior comment:

> A: I care that you seem to be losing your hearing.
>   B: You care **what**?  My hearing is just fine, thank you!

or

> B: You care **what**?  Did I lose an earring?

Comment: Maybe is it also possible to say "hope it/hope that/hope this/hope what/think it/think that/think this/think what" the same way as "insist/care" in your examples?